# count numpy 2D array count

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a list `called months: array([ 1,  1,  1, ..., 12, 12, 12]),`which has 1~12 months
and a list called `best_labels :array([8, 0, 0, ..., 6, 0, 0],` dtype=int32)`, which has 10 clusters (0~9)

both have the same length 72915.

Now I want to make a numpy array called `C[i-1][j]` to count the number of cluster j that was published in month i.

Result should look like this, 12 row(months) * 10 columns(clusters), 
for example, C[0][0] = 5251, which means there are 5251 number of cluster 1 that was happened in month 1.

```
array([[5251,    2,  226,    0,    0,    0,  163,    0,  147,    0],
       [5251,    2,  226,    0,    0,    0,  163,    0,  147,    0],
       [5251,    2,  226,    0,    0,    0,  163,    0,  147,    0],
       [5251,    2,  226,    0,    0,    0,  163,    0,  147,    0],
       [5251,    2,  226,    0,    0,    0,  163,    0,  147,    0],
       [5251,    2,  226,    0,    0,    0,  163,    0,  147,    0],
       [5251,    2,  226,    0,    0,    0,  163,    0,  147,    0],
       [5251,    2,  226,    0,    0,    0,  163,    0,  147,    0],
       [5251,    2,  226,    0,    0,    0,  163,    0,  147,    0],
       [5251,    2,  226,    0,    0,    0,  163,    0,  147,    0],
       [5251,    2,  226,    0,    0,    0,  163,    0,  147,    0],
       [5251,    2,  226,    0,    0,    0,  163,    0,  147,    0]])
```

I've done this, but it has *TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index*

```
C = np.zeros((12,best_k),dtype=np.int)
A = list(zip(months,best_labels))
for i in range(1,13):
    count =0
    for j in range(1,11):
        if C[i]==A[months] and C[j]==A[best_labels]:
            C[i][j] = count+1
```

Comment: If you've pandas, try `pd.crosstab(called_months, best_labels)`

Comment: Thank you! I learn a new way from that !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your loop should be like this

```
C = np.zeros((12,best_k),dtype=np.int)
A = list(zip(months,best_labels))

for month, label in A:
    C[month-1][label] += 1
```